# PSQL: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: java, postgresql, batch-file, psql

I want to write script for create database with tables in PostgreSQL.
I created **deploy_db.bat**:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres -f run_main.sql
pause
```

my run_main.sql:

```
BEGIN;
\i create_db.sql
\i tableA.sql
COMMIT;
```

create_db.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test CASCADE;

CREATE SCHEMA test
  AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

tableA.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test.tableA(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  age INTEGER
);
```

So, I run **deploy_db.bat** and see:

```
BEGIN
psql:create_db.sql:1: ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
psql:create_db.sql:3: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
ROLLBACK
```

But, Why? How can resolved it?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong. You can't run `CREATE DATABASE` inside a `BEGIN ... COMMIT` block.

Comment: Where need to set block "CREATE DATABASE"? How do correctly it?

Comment: Instead of creating a database in the SQL script look at the [createdb utility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html). Execute it firstly in the your batch and then connect to the newly created DB.

Comment: @Abelisto Or just run `CREATE DATABASE` **before the `BEGIN`**. Then you probably want to `\c` to the created database.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, it was proposed in the your comment above and in the answer below. However in my **own** opinion the creating database and the filling it by the objects/data is a bit different things (like formatting diskette and copying files to it :) Moreover, while in the Q mentioned the `psql`, not all clients supports connecting "on the fly" to the another DB in the same script. Finally, separating those operations allows to create the data schema in the databases with different names without editing the SQL script. In short, thats why I proposed to create the DB separately.

Answer (score 1):

You issued `BEGIN` which started a transaction, then `CREATE DATABASE` which produced the error message because you ran it inside the transaction.

You could just move the `CREATE DATABASE` statement before the `BEGIN`, that would get rid of the error message.

But reading your SQL script I suspect that you want to create the new schema and table in the newly created database, which is not what will happen with your script. Rather, the schema and the table will be created in the database `postgres`.

To change that, your script should look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;

-- connect to that database
\connect test

-- now create your schema and your table
CREATE SCHEMA ...
CREATE TABLE ...
```